# ASP.NET Core URL redirect fails without errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a controller `MediaProxyController` that acts as a proxy for media hosted on an external CDN, so that we can track download statistics, etc. An endpoint gets called, updates the stats and then redirects to wherever the resource is.

However, the browser (any of them) doesn't appear to redirect at all, leaving the user with a blank screen, despite no errors.

Interestingly, when I take out the security for handling URL Redirect attacks and change the url to `https://google.com` that does the same thing, leaving the user with a blank screen.

This is what the controller method in question looks like:

```
        [HttpGet("CdnRedirect")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CdnRedirect(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                // Logic to prevent URL Redirect attacks
    
                return Redirect(url);                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log exceptions - not reached
            }

            return BadRequest("There was an error processing your request");
        }
```

It is also worth noting that the `BadRequest` does work correctly, so there is something wrong with how I'm implementing the Redirect itself.

One alternative might be to download the file on behalf of the client and feed it back to them, but that doesn't sit right with me.

What could be preventing the redirect from working correctly?

Comment: _" have a controller MediaProxyController that acts as a proxy for media hosted on an external CDN, so that we can track download statistics, etc. An endpoint gets called, updates the stats and then redirects to wherever the resource is."_ - A redirect is not a proxy...

Comment: Have you checked your browser's DevTools to see what the actual response is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the redirect was actually working as intended. There was another middleware that was trying to rewrite the body and failing with non-text/html content. Fixing that resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

URL needs to have http/https or in another words it needs to be complete. Then it will redirect to that particular URL.

Below code does not redirect to Twitter.

```
        try
        {
            // Logic to prevent URL Redirect attacks

            return Redirect("twitter.com/home");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log exceptions - not reached
        }
```

[image: URL without http/https]

Need full URL's for redirect:

```
            try
            {
                // Logic to prevent URL Redirect attacks

                return Redirect("https://twitter.com/home");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log exceptions - not reached
            }
```

Comment: I can confirm the url is fully qualified with https and is valid